# Facebook connect permissions PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I try to establish a connection to Facebook Connect, the treatment goes well, I can retrieve the user name and id, but the information transmitted in $ permissions are not taken into account. Would I have forgotten a thing?
I followed the docs available on Facebook developers.
I use the latest version: **PHP SDK 5.2**

```
public function facebook() {
    session_start();
    require '../Vendor/autoload.php';
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'ID_APP',
        'app_secret' => 'SECRET_APP',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['email', 'user_location','user_birthday']; // optional
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/Weade/connexion/check_facebook', $permissions);

    $this->redirect($loginUrl);


}
```

```
public function check_facebook() {
    session_start();
    require '../Vendor/autoload.php';
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'APP_ID',
        'app_secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($accessToken)) {
        // Logged in!
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // Now you can redirect to another page and use the
        // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
    }

    if($this->Session->read('facebook_access_token')) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($this->Session->read('facebook_access_token'));

        try {
            $response = $fb->get('/me');
            $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
            debug($userNode);


        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=emai,user_location,user_birthday');
```

You'll have to define which fields you want to retrieve with your request, for example /me?fields=id,name,email,birthday instead of just /me

See 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in v2.4 requires that you explicitly request the field(s) you need for your GET requests. For example, GET /v2.4/me/feed no longer includes likes and comments by default, but GET /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes will return the data. For more details see the docs on how to request specific fields.

Comment: Thank you ! I'm recover all desired values except one, date of birth, I try user_birthday returns me an error and birthday ca send me a basic table.


**Error user_birthday**
`Graph returned an error: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_birthday) on node type (User)`


** Birthday**
` \app\Controller\UsersController.php (line 148)

object(Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser) {
 [protected] items => array(
  'id' => 'ID_USER_FACEBOOK'
 )
}

`


Any idea why birthday does not appear?
thank you

Comment: Thank you, I test it in the day

Comment: No results, the birthday value is not retrieve

     ``$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=birthday');
                    $user = $response->getGraphUser();

                    debug($user);``

I receive only id

Comment: Try to remove the app from your favebook account in the settings click on apps find the app using it's name remove it and try again

Comment: Weird,, I had already tried and I had no change, it recovers me my date of birth is niquel!
Thank you for your help;)